# How to link an anonymous user to a phone number in a Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to build an authentication mechanism similar to Whatsapp and Whatsapp Web using Android on the mobile device, Angular on the web and hopefully Firebase.

I managed to sign in using a phone number on the mobile device, and anonymously on the web. Then, on the web I generated a QR Code for the user id and scanned it using the mobile device. The issue is that I can't find a way to link the anonymous session from the web to the session that's on the mobile device.

I tried to upload the credentials/token/uid together with the scanned code to Firebase Database and use a Firebase cloud function to link the users but it seems that Firebase cloud functions have no way of linking the two.

Is there a way to achieve this using only Firebase as 'back-end'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I managed to do it:

1. I scanned the QR code using the mobile device and decoded it to get the anonymous user id -
   lets call it **webUID**.
2. On the mobile device I called a Firebase Cloud function with webUID as a parameter.
3. In the Firebase Cloud Function I generated a custom token from the caller's uid (the mobile device's uid) and saved it at /users/**webUID**. This is important because that is the only path that the anonymous user on the web can read (Firebase Database rules).
4. On the web I got the custom token from /users/webUID, removed it from the database, signed out and signed in using **signInWithCustomToken** and the provided custom token.

In the end, both devices are signed in with the right credentials and the token is removed from the database.

Comment: You are basing proof of identity based on uid (uids offer no security and are not means for authentication or session management). This is a very poor design from a security perspective. UIDs are not meant to be a means of authentication.

Comment: @bojeil I see. Could you also provide a situation in which a malicious user could, let's say, do something they shouldn't be able to do?

Comment: @bojeil Also, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) is an example from the Firebase Documentation in which they suggest using UIDs in order to secure the database, and this is what I used to secure mine.

Comment: Firebase security rules always validate ID tokens for users before checking the underlying claims and exposing it in their rules. This is done under the hood.

Comment: @SebastianGrigor To do the same as the Firebase SDKs do under the hood, you'd also have to pass the ID token to the server, and then verify it in your Cloud Functions using the Admin SDK.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Now that you mention this, I realize how silly my design was: I was not calling a Cloud Function from the mobile device to trigger the login on the web, but rather saving the webUID to the database and listening to the database in my Cloud Function. While this is more secure since Firebase validates the token under the hood, as both of you mentioned, I suppose it is not as efficient as directly calling the function. Thank you both for the suggestions, I will update my solution.

Comment: As a clarification - I do not have a back-end server. What I meant to say was that I am trying to achieve this by only using Firebase as the 'back-end' (aka Firebase Authentication, Database and Cloud Functions).